# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre Private Key?

Tags: java, base64, firma-digital, openssl

Hola amigos estoy tratando de utilizar un código que carga un Private Key para luego usar para firmar un XML, pero no estoy muy seguro de si hay diferentes tipos de Private Keys. Tengo 2 codigos de llave y no se cual es la diferencia entre los 2, no se como se llaman los estandares de private key así que no se como decodificarlo.

Al decodificar este primer código me funciona bien el codigo que tengo:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Pero al ejecutar el mismo código para firmar con este otro Private key no me funciona.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOwIBAAJBAPVFg+a+uerlT31j07NzDuB+/1WVr0kr+gPch2urY596zBvUma7q
fY/GRhRF4RjDE53YX0jVfdIYiO/6MPuCpxkCAQMCQQCjg61EfyacmN+o7TfM919A
VKo5DnTbcqatPa+dHO0U+zn3iJZ88Y6ggU2/bTKu8eUHe9qRHeBSjLY2NoXaZAyL
AiEA+zZB05bK/hlPSfBH/3JLgCdzxxOLmr45vLqnR1YLrj0CIQD58kXkXLUphbUH
hNoVoAy76yrQW50SmAu65AEg3eDmDQIhAKd5gTe53KlmNNv1hVT23QAaTS9iXRHU
Jn3RxNo5XR7TAiEApqGD7ZMjcQPOBQM8DmqzJ/Iciue+DGVdJ0Kraz6V7rMCIQD6
4xcKSVJ6ZoGmYrCYv0ltoI36+zW8qieuT4/zuBodow==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Y aunque uno dice RSA y el otro no, no entiendo cual es la diferencia o como puedo obtener el segundo partiendo del primero.

Por si ayuda en algo estoy tratando de utilizar el string en el siguiente código:

```
public static PrivateKey convertStringToPrivateKey(String stringKey)
{

    PrivateKey privateKey = null;
    byte[] sigBytes = new byte[0];
    try {
        sigBytes = Base64.decode(stringKey.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(sigBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        privateKey = keyFact.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);  //throws exception

    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "InvalidKeySpecException signedDocument : " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "NoSuchAlgorithmException signedDocument : " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Exception signedDocument : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return privateKey;
}
```

Comment: Estas decodificando desde archivo .jks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clave con `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` es `PKCS#1` y es una clave RSA, basicamente es la key desde la clave PKCS#8 que es el private key que empieza con `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`. El formato PKCS#8 indica que el tipo de clave está incluido en los datos clave en sí.

Podes ver los diferentes tipos de claves en [PKCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS)

En el codigo que muestras estas usando `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`, por eso es que solo puedes leer claves PKCS#8.

Para pasar de PKCS#8 a PKCS#1:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -in file.key -outform pem -nocrypt -out file.pem
```

Para pasar de PKCS#1 a PKCS#8:

```
openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -in file.key -pubout
```

Comment: Gracias pude solucionar el problema gracias al aporte, excelente.